# Get previous props value with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `usePreviousValue` custom hook to get previous props value from my component:

```
const usePreviousValue = value => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};


const MyComponent = ({ count }) => {
   const prevCount = usePreviousValue(count)

   return (<div> {count} | {prevCount}</div>)   
}
```

But in this case, in `prevCount` I always have only the first `count` prop value when a component was rendered, and the next updated prop value is never assigned to it. Are there any ways to properly compare nextProp and prevProp with functional React components?

Comment: In React classes, componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate methods have optional parameters called prevProps and prevState that store previous props and state values

Answer (score 7):

Your code sample seems to be working just fine. How exactly are you using the component? Try to run the snippet below:

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const usePreviousValue = value => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};


const MyComponent = ({ count }) => {
   const prevCount = usePreviousValue(count);

   return (<div> {count} | {prevCount}</div>);
} 

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent count={count} />
      <button
        onClick={() => setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)}
      >
        Count++
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, the easiest way to do it is using a custom hook:

```html
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useComponentDidUpdate = (callback, data, checkIfIsEqual) => {
    const prevData = useRef(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        const isTheSame = checkIfIsEqual ? isEqual(data, prevData) : undefined;
        callback(prevData.current, isTheSame);
        prevData.current = data;
    }, [data]);

    return null;
};

export default useComponentDidUpdate;
```

Then in your component:

```html
const Component = ({age})=>{
const [state, setState] = useState({name: 'John', age})

useComponentDidUpdate(prevStateAndProps=>{
if(prevStateAndProps.age !== age || prevStateAndProps.state.name !== state.name){
   // do something
}

}, {state, age})

...
}
```